# Install nylon straps in chair

Tags: repair, furniture

This is the chair. I’m also including where the plastic steps are held. I’ll be removing the plastic straps and installing 1” nylon straps.

How can I install these straps securely without having to drill additional holes?

I can cut the end of the nylon strap so it fits in the slot, but how do I secure it?

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: rbhat, you're back. We missed you.   This is tough one, i am not sure there is a way to use nylon strap with the existing slots. There may be an alternative fastening method to use with nylon strapping, like rivets ?  Nice photos.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know of this thing called [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how%20to%20replace%20nylon%20strapping%20on%20deck%20chair) ?

Here are just some of the many tutorials i found.

[Vinyl strap video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bipsA6VE0Jg)

[Vinyl strap video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-osTk60qBko)

[Cross strap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4u-QtovOnQ)

[Webbing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXm85cezaKc) *You could adapt it to a metal chair and pan head screws*.

rbhat, i am available for hire, you can buy me a ticket to your tropical paradise and put me on retainer. I have excellent handyman **and** research skills.